# How to install Firefox version 29.0 on Slackware 14.1?

Tags: firefox, synchronization

The problem is that I need to sync Firefox bookmarks between my PC and my notebook, but the notebook uses the Firefox version 29.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and the PC using Firefox version 24.4.0 on Slackware 14.1 64 bits and when I go to Help> about Firefox, it says Firefox is updated. The old sync does not work with the new according to what I read on the Mozilla site, so I need Firefox version 29.0 to sync with the notebook, but I can not find.txz for Slackware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply download tar.bz2 archive from Mozilla site, unpack it to `/opt` and make a symlink to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a handy script that downloads the latest firefox and creates a slackware package.
https://gist.github.com/ruario/9672798

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=mozilla-firefox-29.0.1-i486-1.txz) you are :) Firefox 29 Slackware package.

Comment: This package is for 32 bit, I need 64 bits. Sorry I forgot to say before!

Comment: I downloaded firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2 and unzipped it in /opt, then created a shortcut: ln-fs /opt/firefox/ firefox/usr/bin/firefox 
Problem solved!

Comment: @PattersonSilva could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as helpful, for future questions.

Comment: I do not have enough points to answer my own question!

Comment: @PattersonSilva I've made another answer that satisfies your modified question.